# Sysrepo sr_install_module() not considering search_dirs parameter

Tags: c, libyang

I'm trying to install a sysrepo module with `sr_install_module()`

When calling the following code though, the function seems to dismiss the search dirs parameter as the call fails with the error `libyang[0]: Failed to open file "iana-if-type.yang" (No such file or directory).`

```c
#include "sysrepo.h"
#include "libyang/libyang.h"

sr_conn_ctx_t *srContext;
sr_connect(SR_CONN_CACHE_RUNNING, &srContext);


char *moduleName = "ietf-interfaces.yang";
char *searchDir = "/path/to/dir"
sr_install_module(srContext, moduleName, searchDir, NULL);
```

The module exists in `"/path/to/dir"` but is not found by the call. If I instead use `"/path/to/dir/ietf-interfaces.yang` as the value of `moduleName` the module is found correctly. What am I missing here?